# Converting several files in a folder with ffmpeg rather than just one at a time

Tags: ffmpeg, mp3, bitrate

My MP3 collection is by default saved at a bit-rate of 32k. I like to shrink them down as far as I can before loading on to my “daily driver” MP3-Player.
I found and tweaked what is below with terrific results. Now, I can shrink a single MP3 file down to about 1/4th its original size without enough sound loss for me to notice with my old-ass ears.:

```
$ ffmpeg -i *.mp3 -ac 1 -ab 8000 -ar 22050 BR_8k-SR_22050.mp3
```

So, how can I convert ALL the files in a FOLDER all at once? I don’t mind if the original files are overwritten or if, another folder is created to hold the modified MP3s.

Comment: You can do it with a for loop. On which OS are you operating?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with a `for` loop. The following examples will convert all the files and save the files to a subdirectory named *Output* (the subdirectory must exist before running the command).

In Linux/macOS use:

```
for i in *.mp3; do ffmpeg -i "$i" -ac 1 -ab 8000 -ar 22050 Output/"${i}"; done
```

In Windows use:

```
FOR /F "tokens=*" %G IN ('dir /b *.mp3') DO ffmpeg -i "%G" -ac 1 -ab 8000 -ar 22050 "Output\%G"
```

Comment: Thank you, I forgot to say that I am running Linux. Sadly, the suggestion did not work. It said "Invalid argument"

Comment: I think it was just a typo in the output folder, using a backslash instead of a forward slash. Try now

Comment: Nope. Still nothing.

Comment: Nothing or an error? Can you post the whole command as you used it, as well as the full error? It works for me in Ubuntu terminal without issue.

Comment: for i in *.mp3; do ffmpeg -i "$i" -ac 1 -ab 8000 -ar 22050 Output\"${i}"; done
Output"008-008.mp3; done
for i in *.mp3; do ffmpeg -i 008-008.mp3 -ac 1 -ab 8000 -ar 22050 Output"008-008.mp3: Invalid argument

Comment: Why are you changing the command (adding there _Output"008-008.mp3_)?... And this also seems to still use the old version of my answer (with a backslash instead of a forward slash). Just use `for i in *.mp3; do ffmpeg -i "$i" -ac 1 -ab 8000 -ar 22050 Output/"${i}"; done` (don't modify/add anything in/to it)

Comment: This worked this time! thanks a millionfor i in *.mp3; do ffmpeg -i "$i" -ac 1 -ab 8000 -ar 22050 Output/"${i}"; done